# Factoring/Refactoring a program

Tags: c++, refactoring

What does the term 'poorly factored' and 'refactoring' a program mean? Can you give a simple example to understand the basic difference ?

Comment: I think the term "refactoring" is overused, while "factoring" is almost unheard of. A lot of refactoring would be unnecessary if people knew how to properly FACTOR good code right away, in the first place. And just descriptively recognizing "poorly factored" code does not necessarily help to prescribe the desired characteristics of well-factored code. Being so, +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refactoring is a general technique that can refer to many tasks. It usually means cleaning up code, removing redundancy, improving code quality and readability.

A very simple example of *poorly factored* code:

```
do_task1("abc");
do_task2(123);
do_task3(7.43);
...
//100 lines later:
do_task1("abc");
do_task2(123);
do_task3(7.43);
...
//80 lines later:
do_task1("abc");
do_task2(123);
do_task3(7.43);
```

See how the same set of 3 lines is repeated over and over and over?

Refactoring this code might give:

```
procedure do_tasks1to3(x,y,z)
    do_task1(x);
    do_task2(y);
    do_task3(z);
end

do_tasks1to3("abc",123,7.43);
...
//100 lines later:
do_tasks1to3("abc",123,7.43);
...
//80 lines later:
do_tasks1to3("abc",123,7.43);
```

The refactored code makes use of a procedure to perform the repetitive tasks, and if a `do_task4` ever needs to be added, it only needs to be done inside the procedure, not in 4 separate places like before.

There are other ways to refactor this, and of course if you ever needed to have variance to the `do_taskn` functions this might not work, but this is usually how you'd start...

Comment: The "refactored" code is still pretty poor. Where's the loop? :)

Comment: It seems reasonable that do_task1 is a quick procedure name for the response given here, but an improvement to the spirit of the answer might be to also rename such procedures to have some semantic value. A coworker might much more quickly have an 'ahh' moment when they see 'update_product_inventory' as the procedure name, instead. And this type of improvement falls under the umbrella of a refactor.

Answer (score 7):

Poorly factored means containing redundancies, or organized in a way that makes core dependencies difficult to see. The term initially comes from math:

```
Factoring: Finding what to multiply together to get an expression.
```

There are many ways to factor an expression, just as there are many ways to write a program achieving the same result. As we all know form algebra, finding a suitable factoring can make the whole equation much easier to solve.

Comment: +1 for being the only question explaining what Factoring actually means.

Answer (score 3):

Poorly factored code is code that has been written in such a way as to be difficult to understand, maintain, reuse, etc.

Refactoring generally means to alter the way a piece of code/module/program is written without actually changing its functionality. Some of the goals of refactoring include increased readability, decreased coupling, and easier code reuse (i.e. fixing what's wrong with poorly factored code.)

Answer (score 2):

*Poorly factored* means it was not well crafted. While *refactoring* refers to review and improve code.

Comment: It's a bit more specific than that.  There are lots of ways in which a program can be "not well crafted", poor factoring is just one of them.

Comment: see Code Refactoring in Wikipedia.org - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring

Answer (score 2):

Means of [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring of Code Include:

```
* Clarity: the meaning of the code should be obvious to anyone reading it.  Comments can be refactored as well for adding additional explaination for hairy code, but one should try to make the code itself clear enough to understand

* Eliminate redundant code:  refactoring is the time to recognize patterns and factor them out of your code.  Similar and redundant classes and code blocks should be combined, and unnecessary functions and variables eliminated.

* Modularity and Scalability:  code should be easy to extend or modify, and be able to scale without adding complexity

* Simplicity: Reduce Unnecessary complexity. Complexity should only be considered if it considerably increases readability or modularity ( hence reducing future efforts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically making your code more elegant: removing repetition, making code more maintainable, and more readable.

However, it is possible to refactor code too far. Excess amounts of time can be spend cleaning up code, making it more readable, more robust, etc. This can be bad if you are working under tight deadlines for example a week could be spend refactoring code. With the result being a segment of code which may 'functionally' do the same thing,  but is only more readable, or looks a little prettier.

I find it best to refactor as I go, the occasional renaming of variables, methods etc and doing the larger methods of refactoring when:
a) I know  I'll have enough time. AND 
b) By refactoring this section of code, significant functional/ performance benefits will be gained. (Outweighing the time drawback.)

Just my experience.

I have been told by my colleagues to read Clean Code by Robert Martin :- http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1346277262&sr=1-1

Answer (score 0):

poorly factored means that it has not undergone enough iterative refactorings to remove bad design patterns (ie. anti-patterns).

In general it means it is just poor code.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of it as a math metaphor (and however close it is to a literal correspondence, is not for me to say):

Let's say I work at a fictitious company called 504 Industries and all of my products generate the integer 504. My flagship product is called Cruncher and whenever my customers run it, the number 504 prints up on the screen.

One day, I have auditors inspect the source code and discover that it has some tech debt. The source code looks like this: `113+412-(11+9+1)`

This does give the correct answer, but I find it is difficult to attract new talent to my company to work on this source code. My original vision for 504 was quite simple, so how did this come to be?

Over the years, my developers were free to come up with this algorithm without a lot of design oversight, and customers loved that the answer was always 504. So we kept making money, but it became more difficult to create new releases.

Finally, we decided to refactor our code. Because `113+412-(11+9+1)` was not intuitive, and we knew there was originally a more simple process, that we could re-establish with some careful discovery.

When our refactor was done, Cruncher 2.0 was ready, and the source code was much easier to read: `7*8*9`. Our hiring process became successful, and we even created a new company, 3024 Industries that made some very clever reuse of our code from 504 Industries. (We use our solution for Cruncher 2.0 as a library, multiply the answer by 6, and have our new product 3024, you see. We do not need to invent the `7*8*9` code a second time; we reuse it to save time and money. This is possible because we can refactor any code into a reusable library, a second example of refactoring for today)

As we can see, although we had a perfectly valid product, the cost of maintaining it was able to be reduced at the cost of an optional one time fixed body of work. There was a risk in refactoring it that we may have failed at, and so a refactor is always an event that must be cautiously evaluated.

With the notion that 'Worse is Better' (or, that mediocre solutions that exist and people can use, are superior to perfect solutions that are imaginary), our original version of the 504 product in fact may have been the superior solution if my developers were never able to refactor `113+412-(11+9+1)` as `7*8*9`.